# Is this line of code creating a new instance of the Card class?

Tags: python, class

I want to know what exaclty is the following line of code doing,i would like to receive help to fully understand what is happening in the upper class when i initiate that for loops

```
    import random

    suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
    ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven','Eight','Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
    values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
             'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

    playing = True



    class Card():
        def __init__(self,suit,rank):
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank

        def __str__(self):
            return "{} of {}".format(self.rank,self.suit)

    card = Card(suits,ranks)

    class Deck():

        def __init__(self):
            self.deck = []
            for suit in suits:
                for rank in ranks:
                    self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank)) <======= I want to know what is this performing?

        def __str__(self):
            deck_comp = ""
            for card in self.deck:
                deck_comp += "\n" + card.__str__()
            return "The card is" + deck_comp

        def shuffle(self):
            random.shuffle(self.deck)

        def deal(self):
            single_card = self.deck.pop()
            return single_card

    deck = Deck
```

Comment: `Card(suit,rank)` is creating a new `Card` object, meaning a new card and it's being appended to the list of cards in the `deck`

Comment: The line you've pointed out is creating a new `Card` instance, of suit `suit` and rank `rank`. Looking at the `__init__` of the `Card` class above, you can see it has these two properties. That later means, when you call the object `deck.deck`, you will have a 52 or 54 (depends on if you include jokers, by the looks of it not) length list comprised of `Card` objects. If you call `deck.deck[3].suit` you will get the suit of the third card the deck, or `deck.deck[3].rank` will give you the rank.

Comment: @iAmTryingOK  but is it creating the object with the actual object in the list it is iterating?

Comment: @Recessive I think i got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an instance of a Card to a list. This is something you should read about yourself and then ask a more specific question. Explaining it is difficult since we don't know exactly how much you know and the subject is broad. Relevant reading here:

- [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html)